# How can I rotate any shape or point on an HTML5 canvas around an arbitrary point?

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I have seen a few cases of questions asking how to rotate a shape around a given point and decided to ask this self-answer question myself. So - in relation to HTML5 canvas, or in fact any two-dimensional surface, how can I rotate a shape around an arbitrary x,y point ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out the answer is pretty simple but involves a bit of math that may put some folks off.  I'm using the Konvajs HTML5 canvas library but the code is easily transportable to your own lib. Also, this example is described as rotating a shape, but it's really rotating a point - the origin of the shape - so you could use it for any point-rotation-around-a-point case.

The rotateAroundPoint() function does the work - the rest of the code in the snippet is there to make it a working example.

Lifting this function out we can see that the inputs are the shape - although this could be any object with x, y and rotation properties, the rotation angle in degrees, and the rotation point - again an object with x & y values.

When we rotate around the point we are carrying out the equivalent of a rotation-in-place, followed by a translation (or move). These must be done in this sequence. Also, because of how 2d-drawing works, we have to work out the new position for the move and this depends on the drawing origin of the shape.

The calculation of the new x & y positions requires the use of sine & cosine functions which require radians - not degrees. So we multiply degrees by PI / 180 to get that.

```
// Rotate a shape around any point.
// shape is a Konva shape
// angleDegrees is the angle to rotate by, in degrees
// point is an object {x: posX, y: posY}
function rotateAroundPoint(shape, angleDegrees, point) {
  let angleRadians = angleDegrees * Math.PI / 180; // sin + cos require radians
  
  const x =
    point.x +
    (shape.x() - point.x) * Math.cos(angleRadians) -
    (shape.y() - point.y) * Math.sin(angleRadians);
  const y =
    point.y +
    (shape.x() - point.x) * Math.sin(angleRadians) +
    (shape.y() - point.y) * Math.cos(angleRadians);
   
  shape.rotation(shape.rotation() + angleDegrees); // rotate the shape in place
  shape.x(x);  // move the rotated shape in relation to the rotation point.
  shape.y(y);

}
```

That's it! Have a play with the snippet - best viewed full-screen. Select a shape to rotate, then click the rotate button a few times to watch it spin around its origin (the natural point of rotation if we just change the rotation angle and nothing else). Then click the reset button, and click the canvas to move the blue target somewhere else on the canvas or shape, and rotate some more to see the effect.

There's also a codepen version [here](https://codepen.io/JEE42/pen/yLOPvgq?editors=1111).

```js
// Code to illustrate rotation of a shape around any given point. The important functions here is rotateAroundPoint() which does the rotation and movement math ! 

let 
    angle = 0, // display value of angle
    startPos = {x: 80, y: 45},    
    shapes = [],    // array of shape ghosts / tails
    rotateBy = 20,  // per-step angle of rotation 
    shapeName = $('#shapeName').val(),  // what shape are we drawing
    shape = null,
    ghostLimit = 10,

    // Set up a stage
    stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
      }),

  
    // add a layer to draw on
    layer = new Konva.Layer(),
    
    // create the rotation target point cross-hair marker
    lineV = new Konva.Line({points: [0, -20, 0, 20], stroke: 'cyan', strokeWidth: 1}),
    lineH = new Konva.Line({points: [-20, 0,  20, 0], stroke: 'cyan', strokeWidth: 1}),
    circle = new Konva.Circle({x: 0, y: 0, radius: 10, fill: 'transparent', stroke: 'cyan', strokeWidth: 1}),
    cross = new Konva.Group({draggable: true, x: startPos.x, y: startPos.y});

// Add the elements to the cross-hair group
cross.add(lineV, lineH, circle);
layer.add(cross);

// Add the layer to the stage
stage.add(layer);


$('#shapeName').on('change', function(){
  shapeName = $('#shapeName').val();
  shape.destroy();
  shape = null;
  reset();
})


// Draw whatever shape the user selected
function drawShape(){
  
    // Add a shape to rotate
    if (shape !== null){
      shape.destroy();
    }
   
    switch (shapeName){
      case "rectangle":
        shape = new Konva.Rect({x: startPos.x, y: startPos.y, width: 120, height: 80, fill: 'magenta', stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 4});
        break;

      case "hexagon":
        shape = new Konva.RegularPolygon({x: startPos.x, y: startPos.y, sides: 6, radius: 40, fill: 'magenta', stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 4}); 
        break;
        
      case "ellipse":
        shape = new Konva.Ellipse({x: startPos.x, y: startPos.y, radiusX: 40, radiusY: 20, fill: 'magenta', stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 4});     
        break;
        
      case "circle":
        shape = new Konva.Ellipse({x: startPos.x, y: startPos.y, radiusX: 40, radiusY: 40, fill: 'magenta', stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 4});     
        break;

      case "star":
        shape = new Konva.Star({x: startPos.x, y: startPos.y, numPoints: 5, innerRadius: 20, outerRadius: 40, fill: 'magenta', stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 4});     
        break;        
    };
    layer.add(shape);
    
    cross.moveToTop();

  }



// Reset the shape position etc.
function reset(){

  drawShape();  // draw the current shape
  
  // Set to starting position, etc.
  shape.position(startPos)
  cross.position(startPos);
  angle = 0;
  $('#angle').html(angle);
  $('#position').html('(' + shape.x() + ', ' + shape.y() + ')');
  
  clearTails(); // clear the tail shapes
  
  stage.draw();  // refresh / draw the stage.
}




// Click the stage to move the rotation point
stage.on('click', function (e) {
  cross.position(stage.getPointerPosition());
  stage.draw();
});

// Rotate a shape around any point.
// shape is a Konva shape
// angleRadians is the angle to rotate by, in radians
// point is an object {x: posX, y: posY}
function rotateAroundPoint(shape, angleDegrees, point) {
  let angleRadians = angleDegrees * Math.PI / 180; // sin + cos require radians
  
  const x =
    point.x +
    (shape.x() - point.x) * Math.cos(angleRadians) -
    (shape.y() - point.y) * Math.sin(angleRadians);
  const y =
    point.y +
    (shape.x() - point.x) * Math.sin(angleRadians) +
    (shape.y() - point.y) * Math.cos(angleRadians);
   
  shape.rotation(shape.rotation() + angleDegrees); // rotate the shape in place
  shape.x(x);  // move the rotated shape in relation to the rotation point.
  shape.y(y);
  
  shape.moveToTop(); // 
}



$('#rotate').on('click', function(){
  
  let newShape = shape.clone();
  shapes.push(newShape);
  layer.add(newShape);
  
  // This ghost / tails stuff is just for fun.
  if (shapes.length >= ghostLimit){
    shapes[0].destroy();   
    shapes = shapes.slice(1);
  }
  for (var i = shapes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    shapes[i].opacity((i + 1) * (1/(shapes.length + 2)))
  };

  // This is the important call ! Cross is the rotation point as illustrated by crosshairs.
  rotateAroundPoint(shape, rotateBy, {x: cross.x(), y: cross.y()});
  
  cross.moveToTop();
  
  stage.draw();
  
  angle = angle + 10;
  $('#angle').html(angle);
  $('#position').html('(' + Math.round(shape.x() * 10) / 10 + ', ' + Math.round(shape.y() * 10) / 10 + ')');
})



// Function to clear the ghost / tail shapes
function clearTails(){

  for (var i = shapes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    shapes[i].destroy();
  };
  shapes = [];
  
}

// User cicks the reset button.
$('#reset').on('click', function(){

  reset();

})

// Force first draw!
reset();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10;
  padding: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@^3/konva.min.js"></script>
<p>1. Click the rotate button to see what happens when rotating around shape origin.</p>
<p>2. Reset then click stage to move rotation point and click rotate button again - rinse & repeat</p>
<p>
<button id = 'rotate'>Rotate</button>
  <button id = 'reset'>Reset</button> 
  <select id='shapeName'>
    <option value='rectangle'>Rectangle</option>
    <option value='hexagon'>Polygon</option>
    <option value='ellipse' >Ellipse</option>
    <option value='circle' >Circle</option>
    <option value='star' selected='selected'>Star</option>    
    
  </select>
  Angle :    <span id='angle'>0</span>
Position :   <span id='position'></span>
</p>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry to resurrect an old question but this is exactly the functionality I am trying to implement, albeit using the canvas to drawn an image, with a mask area which I'm using to find the centre point for the rotation.
How would the above be modified to rotate an image around this centre point?

Comment: Its the same - see the demo where you can select rectangle which has the same top-left x,y layout as an image.